# How do you insert a binary reader to string query for mysql?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm learning how to upload images into MySql database. Before you all get cranky and tell me that it's bad practice to upload images into mysql database, I AGREE WITH YOU, but it's for a school project and that's what the school wants.

This is what I found on the net and it works. But I would like to understand it more and maybe modify it to fit my custom subs. Also the datatype for the images is `blob`

```
Dim strFileName as String 'This is the file path
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(cnn.ConnectionString)
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim fs As FileStream
Dim br As BinaryReader

Dim FileName As String = strFileName.ToString
Dim ImageData() As Byte

fs = New FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
br = New BinaryReader(fs)
ImageData = br.ReadBytes(CType(fs.Length, Integer))
br.Close()
fs.Close()

If File.Exists(strFileName) = False Then MsgBox("Cannot locate file") : Return
Dim CmdString As String = "INSERT into tbl_maps(map_name,map_floor,map) Values('" & txtMapName.Text & "','" & cmbMapsFloor.Text & "',@Image)"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(CmdString, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Image", ImageData)
con.Open()
```

Now my question is, is there a way to insert `ImageData` into a string for the `MySqlCommand`? This is how I usually insert data into the database.

```
Public Sub RunQuery()
    On Error Resume Next
    dr.Close()
    InitQuery()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub

Public Sub InitQuery()
    With cmd
        .CommandText = sql
        .Connection = cnn
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub something()
    sql = "INSERT into tbl_maps(map_name,map_floor) Values('" & txtMapName.Text & "','" & cmbMapsFloor.Text & "')"
    RunQuery()
    MsgBox("Data saved successfully") 'or some way to check the data inserted
End Sub
```

I was hoping for something that would maybe look like this

```
sql = "INSERT into tbl_maps(map_name,map_floor,map) Values('" & txtMapName.Text & "','" & cmbMapsFloor.Text & "','" & ImageData & "')"
RunQuery()
```

But I know that's not correct because `sql` is a string and `ImageData` is not. I'm just looking for a way to avoid using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Image", ImageData)` or at the very least integrate it into my `RunQuery` sub.

P.S.: Not that it really matters but I like 1 line code sets. Because I read lines like I read sentences. Example:

```
If RecordNotExist() = true then Msgbox("Record not found") : txtsearch.selectall() : txtsearch.focus() : return
```

Translation: If no records match the search query, search for something else.

Comment: tell your teachers to try PostgreSQL !!!

Comment: Lol. Didn't expect this kind of comment. Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/lo-funcs.html
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column
See why when I see mysql way I feel like running away?